# Android:HorizontalScrollView wrap its child?

Tags: android

I have HorizontalScrollView with RelativeLayout as a child. And here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:scrollbars="none">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
</RelativeLayout>

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

The output is pink color...But I need white...Why Relative Layout didn't filled its parent ?

screenshot:
[image]

screenshot with buttons: [image]

Comment: please clear ur Que ?
what output u want?

Comment: How do you think what output should be when you look at this xml ? Screen with what color ?

Comment: screen will display with pink color... now tell me wat output you are getting and what output u want ?

Comment: I have pink, but why pink ? I want white...because relative layout should fill parent

Comment: can u show me screenshot of ur output plz

Comment: plz add screenshot with 3-4 buttons

Comment: as u can see your relative layout is not same as horizonata...
you should try match parent or if it not work try
LinearLayout

Comment: if u are using horizinatal scroll view why are u adding button verically...you should add button horizonataly

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when you put the buttons in you are not matching the scrollview. try using a `LinearLayout` as your parent then have the scrollview as a child with `match_parent` and then add in your other layout as a child of the scrollview the `match_parent` also